# EF Core Seeding Data Depending on Database Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

As a part of the migration, I need to prefill an SQL Server table with the data where one of the fields should depend on the target *database name* or *server name*. At least it should not be the same for the Development and Production environments.

I wrote a code in `OnModelCreating` using `modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasData(...)` but I still have no idea how to take the target database name here.

Comment: That's storing redundancy, which should always be avoided if possible. The value can be obtained at runtime. Consider what happens if the database is migrated to another server, or even renamed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get database name from your connection string.
Put this code inside the **Seed** method:

```
var connection = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

or something like that, which provide the connection string, then get the database name from that object.